# Get specific info from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with a table called "user"; I want to make a PHP script which will be executed like this: `http://forum.com/phpscript.php?username=MyName`.

It should search the table for that `username` and return the `userid` then.
This is what I have tried after some tutorials:

```
<?php

$servername     = "localhost";
$username       = "username";
$password       = "password";
$dbname         = "database";

$uname      = $_GET["user"];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username = '$uname'"
$result = $conn->query( $sql );

if( $result->num_rows > 0 )
{
    $userid = $conn->result( $result, 0 );

    echo "$userid";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I've executed this by uploading it on the server and calling it from the browser: `http://forum.com/phpscript.php?username=MyName`.

Comment: I totally forgot; this is the error I get:

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/zedcheat/public_html/addusertodb.php on line 22

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon on this line: `$sql = "SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username = '$uname'"`

Comment: Oh my god. That actually fixed it.. Haha how could this happen. Thank you!

Comment: Now see about prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error near $result, (;) is missing after $sql; try this

```
$sql = "SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username = '$uname'";
```

or,

```
$sql = "SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username = '".$uname."'";
```

Comment: I don't have a mysqli instance to hand to play with, but this was never a requirement with the mysql extension. What error code does this return?